# Integrating Google Play services achievements and android notifications

Tags: android, notifications, google-play-services, achievements

I am using Google Play services to set up achievements for an android game.

**Goal:**
In my `onAchievmentUnlocked` callback I want to send a notification to the device that opens the achievement screen when the user touches the notification (from wherever they are).

**What works**:

- The notification gets sent properly and all the icons etc. are visible. Touching the notificatoin does nothing though.
- The achievement activity does work, since I have an Option Menu item to call it up in the app via this code: `activity.startActivityForResult(gameClient.getAchievementsIntent(), ACHIEVEMENTS_ID);`

**What's not working**:
Touching the notification has no apparent effect.

**Notes**:

- MinSDKVersion is 14
- TargetSDKVersion is 16

Here's the code I have at present:

```
@Override
public void onAchievementUnlocked(final String id) {
    final Achievement ac = mAchievementManager.getUnlockedAchievements().get(id);
    assert(ac!=null);
    Uri uri = ac.getUnlockedImageUri();
    final Context ctx = this;
    ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener listener = new ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoaded(Uri uri, Drawable drawable) {
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
                    .setContentTitle(APP_TITLE_STRING)
                    .setContentText(ac.getName() + " achievement unlocked")
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_trophy);
                Intent intent = mLoginFragment.getGamesClient().getAchievementsIntent();
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, AchievementManager.REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
            Notification note;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) note = builder.build();
            else note = builder.getNotification();
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, note);
        }
    };
    mImageManager.loadImage(listener,uri,R.drawable.ic_trophy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code here:

```
Games.Achievements.incrementImmediate(GoogleApiClient apiClient, String id, int numSteps)
.setResultCallback(new  ResultCallback<Achievements.UpdateAchievementResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(UpdateAchievementResult result) {
            switch (result.getStatus().getStatusCode()) {
            case GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_UNLOCKED:
                // the state of the achievement is STATE_UNLOCKED after an increment operation. Continuing to increment an already unlocked achievement will always return this status.
                break;
            case GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_UNKNOWN:
                // the achievement failed to update because could not find the achievement to update.
                break;
            case GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_NOT_INCREMENTAL:
                // achievement failed to increment since it is not an incremental achievement.
                break;
            case GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_UNLOCK_FAILURE:
                // the call to unlock achievement failed.
                break;
            }
        }

    });
```

This code will increment an achievement by how many ever steps you want, and then will call onResult to see the status of your achievement that was incremented.

Here is a link to see more possible statuses: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.UpdateAchievementResult.html