# Google Play Games achievement result status code is always STATUS_OK

Tags: android, google-play-games, achievements

This is my second question here.  I am not 100% on the formatting and etiquette yet.  I apologize in advance.  I have a published app using the BaseGameUtils provided by Google.  My achievements unlock properly, and the popups show properly, using incrementImmediate(parameters) with a result.  However, the result, which I do receive, always comes back as STATUS_OK, even when the call results in unlocking the achievement.  I can't manage to get result.getStatus().getStatusCode() to ever be STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_UNLOCKED.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Has anyone been able to get STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_UNLOCKED as a status code for result???

Comment: Anyone???????????

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code given in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369199/android-play-a-sound-on-achievement-unlocked), it will make your achievement increment by the amount of steps you want.

```
Games.Achievements.incrementImmediate(GoogleApiClient apiClient, String id, int numSteps).setResultCallback(new  ResultCallback<Achievements.UpdateAchievementResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(UpdateAchievementResult result) {
                if (result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_UNLOCKED) {

                }
            }

        });
```

The [`STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_UNLOCKED`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient#STATUS_ACHIEVEMENT_UNLOCKED) indicates that the incremental achievement was also unlocked when the call was made to increment the achievement.

You can also try to check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089592/integrating-google-play-services-achievements-and-android-notifications).

Comment: Thank you.  However that is the EXACT code I found and am using when I encounter the problem.  Could the problem be that the Achievement is not published?

Comment: You can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements) and [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub#publishing_your_game_changes) about Publishing achievements.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but I have poured through all that information before.  I am using the exact code from the above referenced SO which the user states worked for them.  Very frustrating!

Comment: Now that `Games.Achievements` is deprecated we have to use https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/AchievementsClient#incrementImmediate(java.lang.String,%20int) however for me the result of the task is always false, no matter the task is completed or not. Though, the documentation states "This form of the API will attempt to update the user's achievement on the server immediately. The Boolean in a successful response indicates whether the achievement is now unlocked." Any idea?